# sql query, each column in result is a different WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the easiest way to return some results based on dates.
So for example the table is like this

```
product     date     qty
corn        4/18/16   5
corn        4/18/16   1
corn        4/15/16   10
```

I would want the results to be

```
product    4/15/16       4/18/16
corn        10              6
```

So I am grouping by the product, sum the qty, but each column in result will be a different WHERE filedate = .

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is called *pivoting* - the way to do it will depend on your platform, which you have not stated.

Comment: I'm using a SQL db.  using SSMS

Comment: What's the expected result if suddenly the row (corn, 4/20/16, 3) is inserted?

Comment: if a new date is in the source... then when I run my query again it will have a new result column for 4/20/16

Comment: PIVOT is one of the most repeated topic here. There are so many post available with PIVOT, PIVOT with dynamic columns, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT product,date,qty
    FROM Table1
)X 
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(X.qty) 
    FOR date IN([4/18/16],[4/15/16])
)Y
```

For multiple source, you need to write dynamic query like below

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH CTE (DATELIST, MAXDATE) AS
(
    SELECT '01/04/2016' DATELIST, '30/04/2016' MAXDATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, DATELIST), MAXDATE
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATELIST < MAXDATE
) 
SELECT C.DATELIST
INTO #TempDates
FROM CTE C


SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), DATELIST, 120)) 
                    FROM #TempDates
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT product,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                SELECT B.product, B.date, B.qty, D.DATELIST, CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATELIST, 120) PivotDate
                FROM #TempDates D
                LEFT JOIN YourTable B ON D.DATELIST BETWEEN ''01/04/2016'' AND ''30/04/2016''
            ) X
            PIVOT 
            (
                SUM(qty)
                FOR PivotDate IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) P '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: thanks Vignesh... is there a way I can say for EVERY DAY IN APRIL... rather than listing each data specifically?

Comment: Two seconds later OP wrote the comment: "if a new date is in the source... then when I run my query again it will have a new result column".

Comment: @solarissf Yes it's possible. you have to write dynamic sql

Comment: I'm trying to dissect your sample... which section do I replace with my tables?

Comment: I don't understand cols... I see that STUFF creates a string, QUOTENAME adds delimiters.  What is the purpose of this section?  Is cols just a list of the dates I want as columns?

Comment: @solarissf yes. cols will have the list of dates as you said

Comment: thank you... this seems to be what I was looking for.  I haven't got the dynamic sql working yet but I'll keep researching... either way, this looks like the solution... thanks!